# Errno 13 while attempting to plot an HMM with pomegranate

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, pomegranate

I'm trying to plot an HMM model, implemented through the usage of the Pomegranate library.

Calling the plot method with `model.plot()` invokes the following error:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-405034733d4b> in <module>
      3 #unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in result)]
      4 #unique_data
----> 5 model.plot()

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pomegranate\hmm.pyx in pomegranate.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel.plot()

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pomegranate\hmm.pyx in pomegranate.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel.plot()

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py in draw(self, path, format, prog, args)
   1516 
   1517         if path is not None:
-> 1518             fh = self._get_fh(path, 'w+b')
   1519             fh.write(data)
   1520             if is_string_like(path):

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py in _get_fh(self, path, mode)
   1545                 fh = os.popen("bzcat " + path)  # probably not portable
   1546             else:
-> 1547                 fh = open(path, mode=mode)
   1548         elif hasattr(path, 'write'):
   1549             # Note, mode of file handle is unchanged.

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\renda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp672ou8lg'
```

I tried to change the R/W permission on the folder, but it didn't work. Any suggestion?
I'm working on Windows 10, using Anaconda3 environment.

Comment: If you're on windows try running it as an administrator

Comment: I already tried to run the notebook as an administrator by launching the PowerShell with this aforementioned privilege, but it didn't work.